# Where could be the problem in the bubble sort code?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I have problem, the code sorts well "tab", returns the correct result, but "tab2", already returns the wrong result (7 6 4 0 4 1 3 1 5 6 6 7 8 9 9).
Unfortunately, I don't see any error in the code, everything seems correct to me

```
#include <iostream>

void sort(int* begin, int* end) {
    for (int* i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        //std::cout << *i<< std::endl;

        for (int* j = i+1 ; j < end ; ++j) {
            //std::cout << *(j - 1)<<" " << *j << std::endl;
            if (*(j - 1) > *j) {
                std::swap(*(j - 1), *j);
            }
        }
    }
}

void write(int* begin, int size)
{
    while (size > 0)
    {
        std::cout << *begin << ' ';
        ++begin;
        --size;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int tab[10] = { 0, 9, 1, 3, 8, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4 };
    sort(tab, tab + 10);
    write(tab, 10);

    std::cout << '\n';

    int tab2[16] = { 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 0, 9, 6, 7, 1, 6, 3, 1, -100 };
    sort(tab2, tab2 + 15);
    write(tab2, 15);
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Fire up the ol' debugger and step though the `sort` function, keeping an eye out for the program doing something, like storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path, that you didn't expect. That'll be a bug.

Comment: Use small and systematic test cases so you can follow along in the code without getting lost. The smallest failing case I found is `{ 3, 2, 1 }`. (You will notice that once you've bubbled 3 into the right place, you ignore the first element of the array, which is 2. By sheer coincidence, your order of swapping works with the first array.)

Comment: As a side note, there's generally no good reason to use C-style arrays in C++. They have different behavior than every other type in the language. You will save yourself many tears by using C++'s zero-overhead, well-behaved equivalent container: `std::array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two loops and only use the inner loop's index in comparison and swap. The classic bubble sort uses both indexes. The element at the outer index gets the largest value that comes after it.

So the fix is:

```cpp
            if (*i > *j) {
                std::swap(*i, *j);
            }
```

Alternatively, the issue might be that the inner loop's start moves forward before the lowest value reaches the bottom. You can clearly see it if you print the list after each iteration. In this case, the fix would be starting the inner loop not at the outer loop's cursor, but after the first element.

```cpp
    for (int* i = begin; i <= end; ++i) {
        for (int* j = begin+1 ; j <= end ; ++j) {
            if (*(j - 1) > *j) {
                std::swap(*(j - 1), *j);
```